# ontouchstart not available in iPad?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad

i want to hide an element based on touch of the item on iPad. The following link says -https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html,  Safari supports ontouchstart attribute is supported but its not working. What do we do in that case? I can't use any JavaScript. I need to achieve it in html only.

My code:

```html
<div class="myclass" id="overlay" ontouchstart="hideElement()" onclick="hideElement()" onmousedown="hideElement()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible to add `ontouchstart` directly on an html element. Because is only support by Apple extensions. You can see that [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-onselectstart):

> Support Level
>
> Apple extension.

You can use Jquery or different Apple extensions for make that. You can find more details about Apple extensions here:
https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/